# JRuby long-lived objects

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

Is it possible to within a Rails application running on JRuby create a Java object that stays "alive" between HTTP calls?

Let's just as an example say I have a class Counter (ignore the unfashionable singleton, it's for brevity only):

```
public class Counter {
    static Counter instance = new Counter();
    static Counter getInstance() {return instance;}
    private int counter;

    public Counter() {
        counter = 0;
    }
    public void inc() {
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
};
```

Can I in some way call Counter.getInstance().inc() and expect counter to increase between HTTP-calls?

Comment: Doesn't sound robust. Even if this is managed through a "long-lived" object, what about when you restart the environment? How would you persist the counter? Sounds exactly like what databases were invented for. Try redis if you want to store simple key/val pairs or increment counters.

Comment: Yes I know. But is it possible, that's the question.

Comment: The Counter class is an example only. The real world problem is something that doesnt easily fit a database. The question was whether long-lived objects are possible at all.

Comment: Might be worth jumping on IRC for #jruby and/or #java. Sadly, the JRuby community is quite small, and I imagine only a small portion of it makes full use of the Java/JVM underneath. Charles Nutter (creator of JRuby) is usually on IRC, and happy to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

yes - and you should try it out, if you're class was on the class-path (say within a .jar or simply a dir added to $CLASSPATH) you would :

```
Java::counter_package::Counter.getInstance.inc
```

but I think your real confusion is how a Rails app on JRuby usually works - since Java (the underlying platform) has real threads and there's no GIL ... you will run a single process and all your Ruby classes etc. are "long-lived" - they do not "reload" between requests, so you can do a counter in Ruby :

```
module Counter
  include Singleton
  @@count = 0
  def self.inc; @@count += 1 end
  def self.value; @@count end
end
```

and use it as: `Counter.instance.inc` and the value will be kept between requests until you restart (or do a "hot" re-deploy)

p.s. one thing to keep in mind though is thread-safety ... JRuby has a trick to make `@@var +=` somehow "atomic" (it's no way an atomic operation), I recommend using the atomic gem for truly atomic counters or doing `synchronize {}` around such operations